# OpenAPI spec for the nested array of arrays

Tags: openapi, swagger-editor

I am writing an OpenAPI spec in Swagger for one of the API for which the output is a nested array within another array. Below is the sample for the same.

Can someone please guide me as how to describe the output section for such kind of API response ?

```
{
    "version": "1.0",
    "calculatedDateTime": "20230320 134724",
    "brand": [
        {
            "brandCode": "RET",
            "market": [
                {
                    "ValueCode1": "ABC",
                    "ValueCode2": "A192",
                    "product": [
                        {
                            "ProductFeat1": "A9",
                            "ProductFeat2": "100CD",
                            "ProductFeat3": "3",
                            "ProductFeat4": "20230313 000000",
                            "ProductFeat5": "cert"
                        }
                    ],
                    "market_units": {
                        "UnitCategory1": "g/km",
                        "UnitCategory2": 0,
                        "UnitCategory3": "l/100km",
                        "UnitCategory4": "Wh/km"
                    }
                },
               {
                    "ValueCode1": "ORT",
                    "ValueCode2": "ORT",
                    "product": [
                        {
                            "ProductFeat1": "B10",
                            "ProductFeat2": "100CL",
                            "ProductFeat3": "5",
                            "ProductFeat4": "20230314 000000",
                            "ProductFeat5": "cert"
                        },
                        {
                            "ProductFeat1": "H3",
                            "ProductFeat2": "100C8",
                            "ProductFeat3": "2",
                            "ProductFeat4": "20230213 000000",
                            "ProductFeat5": "non_cert"
                        }
                    ],
                    "market_units": {
                        "UnitCategory1": "g/km",
                        "UnitCategory2": 0,
                        "UnitCategory3": "l/100km",
                        "UnitCategory4": "Wh/km"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "legal_units": {
        "LegalUnitCategory1": "g/km",
        "LegalUnitCategory2": "l/100km",
        "LegalUnitCategory3": "Wh/km",
        "LegalUnitCategory4": "km",
        "LegalUnitCategory5": "kg",
        "LegalUnitCategory6": "N"
    }
}
```

I have tried creating an array for the legal_units and market_units object and then tried to reference them in the output, but not able to align them in terms of the exact output.
As of now, below is the output response, that I was trying to create, but in swaggerhub, my API is not showing the correct response structure.

```
schemas:
    controlAttributes:
      type: object
      properties:
        version:
          type: string
          description: version
          example: "1.0"
        calculatedDateTime:
          type: string
          properties:
            type:
              format: date-time
              example: "20230320 134724"
        brand:
          type: array
          items: 
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/brand'
        legal_units:
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/legal-units'           
      description: ControlAttributes
    brand:
      title: brand
      type: object
      properties:
        brandCode:
          type: string
          example: "RET"
        market:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/market'
      description: brand
    market:
      title: market
      type: array
      items:
       properties:
        ValueCode1:
          type: string
          example: "ABC"
        ValueCode2:
          type: string
          example: "A192"
        product:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/product'
        market_units:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/market-units'
      description: market
    product:
      title: product
      type: array
      items: 
       properties:
        ProductFeat1:
          type: string
        ProductFeat2:
          type: string
        ProductFeat3:
          type: string
        ProductFeat4:
          type: string
        ProductFeat5:
          type: string
      description: p
    market-units:
      type: object
      properties: 
        UnitCategory1:
          type: string
        UnitCategory2:
          type: integer
        UnitCategory3:
          type: string
        UnitCategory4:
          type: string
      description: market-units
    legal-units:
      type: object
      properties:
        LegalUnitCategory1:
          type: string
        LegalUnitCategory2:
          type: string
        LegalUnitCategory3:
          type: string
        LegalUnitCategory4:
          type: string
        LegalUnitCategory5:
          type: string
        LegalUnitCategory6:
          type: string
      description: legal-units
```

Comment: Can you post your current OpenAPI definition and indicate how its output is different from what you expect?

Comment: From your question it is impossible to understand what you are asking for.